# When is the willFocus event emitted? (react-navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Let's assume the following simple scenario:

We have two screens, **A** and **B**.
We're navigating from screen **A** to screen **B**.
React Navigation emits the **willFocus** event for **B**

```
class B extends React.Component (

    componentDidMount(){
        fetchServerData() // fetches some data
    }

    render(){
      <View>
        <NavigationEvents
          onWillFocus={someFunc}
        />
      </View>
    );
}
```

I've noticed that **someFunc** will run anyway, however this makes me wonder, when is the **willFocus** event emitted from React Navigation? I would expect the first time that **someFunc** would not run as the event is emitted at the moment we instruct screen **A** to navigate to screen **B** and therefore the listener for **B** isn's set yet.

This would also serve my (and i imagine many other people's) use case as with the current implementation, **fetchServerData** would run twice. This forces me to add a delay on rendering NavigationEvents otherwise i face data being fetched twice.

Any insights on this?

---

*EDIT: What i've been doing so far is rendering **NavigationEvents** after a **loading** state prop is set to false, by that time it's late enough to set up the **willFocus** listener but it bugs me that the docs dont describe when the **willFocus** event is emitted*

Answer (score 1):

The navigation events are emitted when the parent navigator's state updates.

> I would expect the first time that someFunc would not run as the event is emitted at the moment we instruct screen A to navigate to screen B and therefore the listener for B isn's set yet.

In React, the child's componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate is called first before parent's componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate are called. Because parent can't finish updating until child has finished updating.

So by the time parent finishes updating and emits the events, the child has already mounted and added the listener.